# JsonMappingException when serializing generic object with custom serialization method

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I had a problem with serializing a generic object in Jackson. I've found a workaround, but I still don't know why my original solution doesn't work. Here is my setup:

```
public class ClassA<P>{
    protected final LinkedList<P> list;

    public ClassA(LinkedList<P> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}

@JsonValue
public class ClassB extends ClassA<ParamClass>{
    public ClassB(LinkedList<ParamClass> list) {
       super(list);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public ClassB(int[] array) {
        this(getList(array));
    }

    public int[] serialize(){
        ...
    }
}

public class ParamClass extends BaseParamClass{
    public int getInt(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is my current code for serialize method that works:

```
@JsonValue
public int[] serialize(){
    int[] array = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        BaseParamClass paramClass = list.get(i);
        locationsArray[i] = paramClass.getInt();
    }
    return locationsArray;
}
```

And here is what should work, but does not:

```
@JsonValue
public int[] serialize(){
    int[] array = new int[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        ParamClass paramClass = list.get(i);
        locationsArray[i] = paramClass.getInt();
    }
    return locationsArray;
}
```

With the second case, I get this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException(packages.BaseParamClass cannot be cast to another.packages.ParamClass)
```

What cause this? From type specification in ClassB, it's clear that only ParamClass, not BaseParamClass can be used in the list. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Jackson's `ObjectMapper` the generic type of the target class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory factory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
JavaType paramClassType = factory.constructType(ParamClass.class);
JavaType classBType = factory.constructSimpleType(ClassB.class, new JavaType[]{paramClassType});
mapper.readValue(src, classBType);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any relation between your code and my question. The exception occurs during serialization, not during deserialization. Also, **I know about other solutions** (see working solution in my question), but I want to know why my first solution doesn't work.